# Select only .csv file type to upload to Flask

Tags: python, file, csv, uploading, flask-uploads

How can I restrict uploads to Flask to only permit `.csv` files to be uploaded? I have been trying but can't do it.

So far I have managed to block ALL FILES or upload all of them. I need upload only `.csv` files.

This is what I have tried:

```py
UPLOAD_FOLDER = "/Users/osito/Desktop/efisys-git/efisys/Webb_App/static/archivos"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['csv'])

def allowed_file(filename):
return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route("/carga", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def carga():
if request.method == "POST":  
archivo = request.form['archivo']  
    if archivo.filename == "":
        flash(u"NO selected file", 'error')
    if not allowed_files(archivo.filename):
        flash(u'only csv files', 'error')                                              

    return redirect(request.url)  
return render_template('home.html')
```

And this is the HTML..

```html
<input id="upload" type="file" name="file" onchange="readURL();"/>
<form action="/carga" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h2>Suba Aquí su Archivo CSV </h2>
    <div class="form-group area">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="archivo" id="archivo">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="archivo" class="btn btn primary">Subir</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you please provide a code example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have already posted some code below

Comment: Thank you, I already deleted them.. Sorry I am new usgin stackoverflow too.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this article out might help :D

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

There is an example  which allows you to specify allowed extensions

**ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}**

So try to replace it with one input which is csv in your case

Answer (score 0):

A condition like this might do the trick:

```
if filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()=='csv':
# >>> process file here <<<
```

EDIT: In the meantime I see you have added some more code.
You have a function named `allowed_file`. But you are calling allowed_file**s** further down:

```
if not allowed_files(archivo.filename):
        flash(u'only csv files', 'error')
```

Is that where you are going wrong or is it just a typo in the question?

Comment: Thank you.. it just a typo... but i solved the problem with this..... 

if filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()=='csv':
# >>> process file here <<<

Thak you so much

Comment: No worries. If it solved the problem, please close the question by marking this answer as Accepted.